# Page-layout -> getPrintArea() in office-JS is returning blank Object

Tags: reactjs, office-js

we are working on developing excel add-in using office-JS and We are using "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" official production API's.

we are able to set the "setPrintArea" to the given range through the API, But when we are trying to get the added print-area using getPrintArea() of pageLayout it is always returning blank JSON object "{}", as per documentation expectation is Object of RangeAreas.

My sample code is as follows -

```
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
sheet.pageLayout.setPrintArea("B4:D30");
sheet.load("pageLayout");

await context.sync();

console.log(sheet.getPrintArea());
```

OUTPUT: `Object {}`

**Can anyone please help and let us know what we are missing here?**

Comment: What do you get if you call `console.log(JSON.stringify(sheet.getPrintArea()));`?

Comment: Thank you @RickKirkham for Reply.

Sorry my mistake in the code  **"sheet.getPrintArea()" **,  corrected statement is **"sheet.pageLayout.getPrintArea()".**

I tried console.log(JSON.stringify(sheet.pageLayout.getPrintArea())); but still getting empty JSON Object  like **"{}"**.

Comment: Hi @RickKirkham Can you please check and help me on this?

Comment: I'm going to need you to reproduce this with the [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) tool. Then export the gist of your code and provide a link to the gist in your question.

Comment: Hi @RickKirkham -> Please find the script-lab script link here -> [https://gist.github.com/swarke/31a8b428ec5c182a19225f67e650ed00]

You can change the range on your workbook and test it.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a get* method, it creates a whole new proxy object, which you then have to load and sync before you can read it. So the call to `getPrintRange` has to come *before* the load and sync. The following code works:

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
  const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  sheet.pageLayout.setPrintArea("B4:D30");

  let printArea = sheet.pageLayout.getPrintArea();
  printArea.load("address");
  await context.sync();

  console.log(printArea);
  console.log(printArea.address);
});
```